# Typing middleware with redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm developing a webapp using TypeScript and `redux-toolkit`.

**tl;dr**

How to the set the type for `dispatch` parameter on a middleware?

---

I need to fetch some data from my server and save it on my store. So I wrote a code like bellow (simplified):

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { TNewOrder } from '../store'

const initialState: TNewOrder = {
  prices: [],
  // other stuffs...
}

const newOrderSlice = createSlice({
  initialState,
  name: 'new-order',
  reducers: {
    setPrices(state, action) {
      const { payload } = action

      return {
        ...state,
        prices: payload.prices
      }
    },

    updateFormData(state, action) {
      // not important...
    }
  }
})

const { setPrices, updateFormData } = newOrderSlice.actions

const fetchPrices = () =>
  async (dispatch: any) => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonbox.io/box_4186ae80994ed3789969/prices/5de7e570de45ab001702a382')
    const { prices } = await response.json()

    dispatch(setPrices({ prices }))
  }

export { fetchPrices, updateFormData }
export default newOrderSlice.reducer
```

Note that, because to get fetch a data is an async task, I can't put it directly on `setPrices`. So I created a middleware called `fetchPrices` to do the request task and call `setPrices`.

Despite it works, I'm unhappy with this solution because I set an `any` type. How is the correctly way to set a better type? I can't found a way to import `ThunkDispatch` from `redux-toolkit`.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ThunkDispatch` is not exported by `@reduxjs/toolkit`. You should import it from `redux-thunk` if you want to use it.

```
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk'; 

const fetchPrices = () =>
  async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch) => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonbox.io/box_4186ae80994ed3789969/prices/5de7e570de45ab001702a382')
    const { prices } = await response.json()

    dispatch(setPrices({ prices }))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [official suggestion](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#typing-the-usedispatch-hook) is to use `typeof store.dispatch`, as Redux-Toolkit's `store.dispatch` already includes `ThunkDispatch`. (And you can extend `store.dispatch` if you use additional middlewares and have everything in a central location then.)

In addition, please also take a look at the [TypeScript documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type) of Redux-Toolkit. If you miss anything imporant, please open an issue and let us know :)

Comment: Thank you, but I found another solution using hooks to perform an async task =]